# dbm.error: db type is dbm.bsd, but the module is not available (Python 3.0)

Tags: python-3.x, bsd, dbm, panda3d

I'm trying to open a shelve file that I created in 2.5, but I get the error I listed in the question title.

The data aren't essential, but I really want them.

Looking at the `lib\dbm\__init__.py` file it recognizes 4 types of dbm modules but only finds dbm.dumb on my system.

Does anyone know how I can open this?  
Is there a bsd.py file like the dumb.py file?  
Would I have to install 2.5 to get at it?

Also, I may have had Panda installed on my old installation when I created this file.  
Is the Python installation that comes with Panda standard or might this file have come with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[bsddb](http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html) is part of Python 2.5 (AND 2.4 AND 2.6...) but not of 3.0 -- it was removed (long story...:-).  Get it for 3.0 from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3/4.7.6), recover your data into some other form (sqlite is my personal recommendation), and live happily ever after!-)